# Cannot invoke 'valueForKey' with an argument list of type '(anyObject?)'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I keep getting the error:

> Cannot invoke 'valueForKey' with an argument list of type
>   '(anyObject?)'

when I attempt to convert:

```
NSError* error = [notification.userInfo valueForKey:ZDA_WEB_VIEW_FAILED_ERROR];
```

from Objective-C to Swift.  My best attempt has been the following Swift code:

```
var error: NSError = notification.userInfo.valueForKey(ZDA_WEB_VIEW_FAILED_ERROR)
```

but this doesn't seem to work. Any help will go a long way, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error because `notification.userInfo` returns an optional which must be unwrapped.  The Swift way to do this would be:

```
if let error = notification.userInfo?[ZDA_WEB_VIEW_FAILED_ERROR] as? NSError {
    // use error
}
```